# Calling WebApi from webforms looses authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am trying to upgrade some parts of an old project, and ran across the issue of calling the webapi from the aspx.cs.

When i call the webapi from the htmlpage/angularjs, the request is authenticated and everything works fine.

When i try to call it from the aspx page, even though this.User is Authenticated(on the aspx page), when the call is recieved in the controller, the user is not set and therefor not authenticated.

- We are using owin cookie based authentication.
- On framework 4.7.

Is there any way to authenticate the webapi call, by include the RVT cookie or something?

the call:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var accessList = GetAccessList();
    }



    private List<ClientAccessEntityWithStatisticsDto> GetAccessList()
    {
        string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        ApiHelper.InitializeClient(baseUrl);
        string apiUrl = ApiHelper.ApiClient.BaseAddress + "/client/api/ClientAccess/ClientsUserCanAccessWithStatistics/";
        var task = Task.Run(() => ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(apiUrl));
        task.Wait();

        return task.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ClientAccessEntityWithStatisticsDto>>().Result;
    }
}
```

The helper:

```
public class ApiHelper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
        };
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone coming across this.
Just parse all the request cookies to the api call, and it works like a charm.